# JavaFX: how to create instances of application with different listener bodies

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX. I created an application with three elements: a TextField for entering a number, a "calculate" button and a label for displaying the result. The listener is added to the "calculate" button, in the body of which the result is calculated by the formula.

Question: How can I use this interface for many applications with other formulas in the body of that listener? Of course, you can simply copy and paste the code, rewriting only the body of the listener, but I'm looking for an object-oriented method. Thanks.

How can I do this right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [ask] help section. You need to be more specific in your question. Show what you've done so far (include the code) and clearly explain what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always access the controller and plug in any object you want.

For example:

```java
public Class CalculatorController
{
   private ICalculator calculator; //interface to a calculator object

   // Add the other variables such as the textField, etc.

   public void onCalculateClicked(ActionEvent event)
   {
        String expressionToCalculate = textField.getText();
        String solution = calculator.calculate(expressionToCalculate); // this is the function in the ICalculator interface
        solutionLabel.setText(solution);

   }

   public void setCalculator(ICalculator calculator)
   {
       this.calculator = calculator;
   }

}
```

When you are instantiating your calculator window, it should look something like this

```java
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); 
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Calculator.fxml")); 
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Calculator.css").toExternalForm());

            CalculatorController controller = loader.<CalculatorController>getController(); //Gain a reference to the Controller
            ICalculator myFibonnaciCalculator = new FibonnaciCalculator(); // FibonnaciCalculator implements ICalculator
            controller.setCalculator(myFibonnaciCalculator); // set the type of calculator you want to use.

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this code, the calculator (in this example Fibonnaci) is being injected into the the controller.
You can reuse the CalculatorController class with its corresponding fxml, and you can set whatever calculator object depending on the formula you want to calculate.
Note that this code will cause a null pointer exception if setCalculator is not called.

I am not too sure if this answered your question. It would be nice if you included code next time.